# Is the redistributable ReportViewer 2010 RC available in other languages?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, reportviewer

I need to deploy the language packs for the ReportViewer 2010 control (the english one is installed and working perfectly).  Before, with ReportViewer 2008 and 2005, all the supported laguages were available on the MS downloads site.  I can't seem to find them for the RC of 2010 -- are they available anywhere?

From MSDN:

> To use the localized version of the
>   ReportViewer control redistributable
>   that comes with Visual Studio, do the
>   following:
>
> 1.Run ReportViewer.exe.
>
> 2.Navigate to the folder that contains the language pack you want to use.
>   Language pack folders are located at
>   %PROGRAMFILES%\Microsoft
>   SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\BootStrapper\Packages\ReportViewer\.
>
> 3.Run ReportViewerLP.exe.

Is there  a generic language pack for VS 2010 RC that would have the localized report viewers as well?

Answer (score 1):

It is not more easy to implement the `IReportViewerMessages3` interface?

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.reporting.webforms.ireportviewermessages3%28v=VS.100%29.aspx)

```
 public interface IReportViewerMessages3 : 
                         IReportViewerMessages2, IReportViewerMessages
```

This implementation is loaded by the ReportViewer control via a custom application setting in the Web.config configuration file with the key ReportViewerMessages

```
<appSettings> 
<add key="ReportViewerMessages" value="MyNamespace.MyClass, APP_CODE" /> 
</appSettings>
```

Or if you are on winForms or WPF:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        CCustomMessageClass myMessageClass = new CCustomMessageClass();

        reportViewer1.Messages = myMessageClass;

        this.reportViewer1.RefreshReport();

     }
}

public class CCustomMessageClass : IReportViewerMessages
{

    #region IReportViewerMessages Members

    public string BackButtonToolTip
    {
        get { return ("BackButtonToolTip here."); }
    }

    ...


    #endregion
}
```

Comment: thats possible, but usually reserved for implementing a language that isn't supported.  Plus, I'd have to translate everything into French myself.  Its probably easier just to install the french version of VS 2010 in a VM, and grab the install from there...

Comment: Is not that hard, there is about ~15 terms to translate.